# Factorising an integer in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So I just completed this exercise:
[image]

My solution involved taking norms, deducing that $N(\alpha)=p$ for some $\alpha\in\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ which is not a unit. Then supposing $$\alpha=a+b\sqrt{-2}$$ which means $$N(\alpha)=a^2+2b^2=p$$ then $$(a+b\sqrt{-2})(a-b\sqrt{-2})=p$$

My question is , can the same result not be deduced when we remove the assumption that $p$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}$ and just consider $p$ as any integer.

Comment: "Any" integer cannot be since the norm is non negative so with negative integers it won't work.

Comment: But for non-negative integers it would ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is *No*:

> If $n \in \mathbb Z$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$, can $n$ be factored as $n=\alpha\alpha^*$ ?

Indeed, a necessary condition is that $n$ is a norm because $n=\alpha\alpha^*$ implies $n=N(\alpha)$.

Take $n=10 = 2 \cdot 5$. Then $n$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ because neither $2$ nor $5$ are units in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$.

But $10$ is not a norm in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$.

Comment: but $4=2.2$ and $6=(2+\sqrt{-2})(2-\sqrt{-2})$

Comment: @ConnorBishop, I've added my interpretation of your question. If that wasn't what you meant, please clarify your question.

Comment: The original exercise asks to show that you can find 2 factors, one which is the conjugate of the other. It doesn't say to prove that $p=\alpha\beta$ implies $\alpha^*=\beta$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With this is mind, why is $p$ guaranteed to be a norm if it is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}$ (prime)

Comment: @ConnorBishop, ask a separate question.